# Problema con WHERE en campo temporal

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo este query que me calcula la distancia entre 2 puntos dadas ciertas coordenadas.

El query corre bien, el problema es el WHERE de la consulta, este es el error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'dist' in 'where clause'

Si corro el query sin el WHRE si me arroja el resultado que quiero el problema es el WHERE.

Qué estoy haciendo mal

```
SELECT p.*,
(
    6371 * 
    (2 *
        atan2(
                sqrt(
                        (
                            sin(
                                radians(
                                            (p.Punto_Latitude__c - 19.4326077) / 2
                                        )
                                )

                            *

                            sin(
                                radians(
                                            (p.Punto_Latitude__c - 19.4326077) / 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                        +

                        (
                            cos(
                                radians(19.4326077)
                                )

                            *

                            cos(
                                radians(p.Punto_Latitude__c)
                                )
                        )

                        *

                        (
                            sin(
                                radians(
                                            (p.Punto_Longitude__c - (-99.015725)) / 2
                                        )
                                )

                            *

                            sin(
                                radians(
                                            (p.Punto_Longitude__c - (-99.015725)) / 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    ),

                    sqrt(1 -
                        (
                            sin(
                                radians(
                                            (p.Punto_Latitude__c - 19.4326077) / 2
                                        )
                                )

                            *

                            sin(
                                radians(
                                            (p.Punto_Latitude__c - 19.4326077) / 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                        +

                        (
                            cos(
                                radians(19.4326077)
                                )

                            *

                            cos(
                                radians(p.Punto_Latitude__c)
                                )
                        )

                        *

                        (
                            sin(
                                radians(
                                            (p.Punto_Longitude__c - (-99.015725)) / 2
                                        )
                                )

                            *

                            sin(
                                radians(
                                            (p.Punto_Longitude__c - (-99.015725)) / 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    )

            )
    )
) as dist
FROM places as p
WHERE dist > 100
```

Comment: Sin el WHERE ¿qué resultados trae?

Comment: Todos los campos que tiene la tabla, y se agrega el campo "dist" al final con el càlculo

Comment: el error es correcto. el campo dist no existe en la tabla places.

Comment: Eso es correcto, indiscutible diría yo, pero entonces como puedo filtrar por el campo temporal que se creo.

Answer (score 2):

El error es correcto. El campo dist, no existe en la tabla places. En general, las bases de datos lo ultimo que procesan son los AS, ya que no inciden sobre el resultado de un query.

Por lo tanto, lo que podes hacer es algo asi:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (todo tu select sin el where) 
WHERE dist > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, si les sirve, es con `HAVING` en lugar de `WHERE`.

```
select p.*,
       (...) as dist
from places as p
having dist > 100
```

Comment: having dist? o having y toda la funcion? podrias ser mas claro para los proximos que vengan a ver la respuesta? gracias!

Comment: @gbianchi: OP cambió `where` por `having`. En efecto, como la claúsula `having` es procesado *después* del `select` (a diferencia de la claúsula `where`), entonces la claúsula sí puede hacer referencia al alias `dist`. En lo personal, prefiero tu respuesta, pero lo que propone OP es válido también, aunque no es la forma acostumbrada de usar esa claúsula.

Comment: @sstan mi comentario fue antes de la edicion. Y justamente porque la respuesta no aclaraba eso.